# Android gradle Build failed with an exception

Tags: android

I am getting this error `Error:null value in entry: otherFileOutputs=null` when gradle builds. How can I debug it?

Comment: Add some more info..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove the `.gradle` directory from the root project directory and rebuild your app. This will fix your problem.

Comment: And place it in which directory?

Comment: You no need to place it anywhere, just delete `.gradle` from your project root folder and rebuild your app using `Build => Rebuild Project` from `Android Studio`

Comment: Great! you can accept the answer if it helped you :)